# Rails 3.1 Production - Javascript loads, but doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku

I've just uploaded my app to the heroku servers (with cedar stack) "http://hollow-waterfall-4266.herokuapp.com/" and I can see that the files load and are there, but they don't execute.

The css-file is fine and working, but the javascript files aren't. I've looked at a lot of other posts, but nobody seems to have the answer and I have no idea of where to start to debug this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Enable your javascript console and reload the page. You'll see quite a few javascript errors. It looks like the link to your jQuery file is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had messed up my whole asset pipeline. Started a new rails app.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is throwing "jQuery is not defined" errors. Your page's source looks like this:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery-9750cb66f964a0901c68c61b399928dc.rails" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-1.4.4-d1fb061dfe072deb1a689fdc40b2debe.min" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/countdown-1a430b19ccddfaa55e613c153529478d.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-1e7a267339e7c1853437734d5040d838.infieldlabel" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/charCount-0f5848b48fc67330a2532bbce115bc9c.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application-0dd84c1347591b7d784745c6f5602f7b.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jQuery should be the first JS file you load before any others. Right now, the unobtrusive JS file is loaded before the actual jQuery 1.4.4 file. Also, it looks like the link to the jQuery file (jquery-1.4.4-d1fb061dfe072deb1a689fdc40b2debe.min) doesn't work.

Comment: Just noticed that. I moved the jquery.rails, but I still have absolutely no idea why some of the javascript files are missing the .js in the end. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you paste you error stack? and What heroku stack, rails and ruby version are you using?