# Rails 3.1 Production - Javascript is missing .js endings on deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku, asset-pipeline

I've just made my Rails app and deployed it to Heroku. A very weird thing happened in the process though. Half of my javascript-files are missing their endings (.js). I have absolutely no idea why this is.I've searched far and wide, but I don't seem to find an answer.

My production-config looks like this:

```
  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.precompile << '*.js'
```

Any suggestions?

Posted this other similar question 1 hour ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049023/rails-3-1-production-javascript-loads-but-doesnt-execute). Sorry for the spamming.

Comment: What stack are you using on Heroku? What version of rails and ruby are you using?

Comment: you should use serve_static_assets = false for heroku/production

Comment: Have you tried running the thin server in production on your own machine to see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? You didn't show where your js files are included. If they have dots in the name, apparently you need to tell Rails.
[asset:precompile for .js files? rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346460/assetprecompile-for-js-files-rails-3-1)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I asked this question over a month ago. I can't even remember how I made it work. Thank you very much for answering the question though.